# read MP3 from http with node.js

Tags: node.js, file, http, mp3

I tried to read an MP3 from internet but each time I try to run the API I get this error :

```
throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\ahmedfadhel.achour\Desktop\watson_analyzer\song1.mp3'
```

I am using Watson speech to text to convert this audio mp3 to text. I used request to read the link and then piped it like this

```
var request = require('request')
var fs = require('fs');
var params = {
  audio: request('http://www.castingmachine.com/medias/combeau_marie_1179/audio_af0eacfbc42c4faeabe8bdeb678cd913.mp3').pipe(fs.createReadStream('song1.mp3')),
  // From file
  //audio : fs.createReadStream('public/dnc2004speech.mp3'),
  content_type: 'audio/mp3; rate=44100',
  continuous: true,
  model:'fr-FR_BroadbandModel',
  word_confidence: false,
  interim_results: false,
};   
 let convert = await speechToText.recognize(params)
  .then(transcript => {

    return JSON.stringify(transcript.results.map(res=>res.alternatives[0].transcript).join(''), null, 2);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    return err;
  }); 

  console.log('convert',convert)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It is not clear for me what you try to achieve.  Do you want to download the mp3 file and write it to song1.mp3 file?

Comment: I want just to read the mp3 from that link without downloading or creating any copy of the file on server side. Is that possible ? just read it from the link

Comment: Do you mean play it or just read it.  Because if you only need to read I don`t get the point.  Can you explain the bigger picture of what you try to do?

Comment: Try to remove `.pipe(fs.createReadStream('song1.mp3'))`, it's incorrect and unnecessary. Also, you should say that you are using `ibm-watson`, it's very important to understand context behind code snippet.

Comment: How is `params` used?  Can whatever you're using handle a stream?  If not, you need to write this file to disk first... but actually do that.  Here you're creating a *read* stream which isn't going to help you.

Comment: I edited the code to show you how params is used. I am trying to convert the file into text with watson speech to text service. I removed `.pipe(fs.createReadStream('song1.mp3'))` but now I am getting this : `convert { Error: You cannot pipe after data has been emitted from the response.`